# Enforce element contents based on it's attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem, I can't seem to find solution to, using only XML 1.0. My task is to create schema that will validate xml element differently based on a value of one of it's attributes. Here is simplified example:

```
<elements>
    <elem type="A">
        <foo/>
    </elem>
    <elem type="B">
        <goo/>
    </elem>
</elements>
```

So I would like to check that all `elem`'s of `type="A"` can only have child element `foo` and all `elem`'s of `type="B"` can only have child element `goo`.
What I was able to create so far was this schema.

```
<xs:element name="elements">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="elem" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="elem">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="foo"/>
            <xs:element ref="goo"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="elem-type" use="required">
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="elem-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: XSD 1.0 cannot express your constraint.  See duplicate link for how to do it in XSD 1.1.

Comment: In XSD 1.0 (or even XSD 1.1), you can avoid the issue by naming your elements less generically than `elem`:  `<A/>` and `<B/>`, for example.

Comment: Yes I know but I can't rename the elements since it's part of a assignment.

Comment: Well then you use XSD 1.1 or you enforce your constraints out-of-band wrt XSD.